# Rails 5 nested routing error for edit and destroy after removing directory names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have nested routes for my app for models locations, categories, subcategories and products.  I removed the directory paths by appending , `path: ' ' to each route` like I did for my pages model and the root path. The app works perfectly except when I click the edit and destroy links. The error I receive is `can't find record with friendly id: "edit"`

Side-note, I know most won't agree with nesting 4 deep, but its done for a very specific reason so I get fixed urls patterns that the search engines will index and rank.  How can I remove the directories and retain editing?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/webhooks/stripe'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :locations do
    resources :categories, path: '' do
      resources :subcategories, path: '' do
        resources :products, path: ''
      end
    end
  end


  root 'pages#show', defaults: { id: 'my-little-carnival' } # shows home page as default from pages controller
  get '/pages/list' => 'pages#index' # sets pages index page before setting path to ''
  resources :pages, path: ''
end
```

**Top of Stack Trace**

```
Started GET "/locations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-28 20:41:37 -0800
Processing by LocationsController#index as HTML
  Rendering locations/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered locations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_main-menu.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_standard-page.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 71.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/locations/san-diego/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-28 20:41:39 -0800
Processing by SubcategoriesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"location_id"=>"san-diego", "category_id"=>"edit"}
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "san-diego"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "edit"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: paths are processed top-to-bottom. I'm guessing that your problem is, given how you've arranged things, that your paths are matching in unexpected ways. It's hard to get a good feel for, however, without a more complete stack trace (the first handful of lines).

Comment: @jvillian I added the top part of the stack trace to the question.  Looks like with the path set as `path: ' '` it is skipping down and using the controller beneath it.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but is that the very top? I was thinking there would be `Started GET "/blah/blah/blah" for 127.0.0.1 at ...`. I'm still on Rails 4. Maybe it's different now.

Comment: @StudioRooster, can you show the `rake routes` output?

Comment: @jvillian sorry, I revised the question to show the trace at locations index and then locations edit

Comment: @StudioRooster, I think the problem is in both - the way you are using `friendly_id` gem and your routes.
It treats `edit` in your url `"/locations/san-diego/edit" ` as a record's (`category`) id, not as an action's name.

Comment: @RedZagogulin You are absolutely right.  Can I use an :except option in the nested routes for the :edit ?

Comment: I don't think it is the correct way (you'll end up without an `edit` route at all). Maybe something with urls bounded to your links/buttons (or something that triggers the request)?
1. your URL `/locations/san-diego/edit` says that you want to edit a `Location` record, named "san-diego";
2. Your route treat it like a part of a category path.
3. And everything is served by a `SubcategoriesController`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, if you *really* want to keep that format you had, how about:

```
resources :locations, param: :location_id
base = "locations/:location_id"
['category','subcategory','product'].each do |seg|
  get     "#{base}/#{seg.pluralize}",       to: "#{seg.pluralize}#index",   as: seg.pluralize
  post    "#{base}/#{seg.pluralize}",       to: "#{seg.pluralize}#create"
  get     "#{base}/#{seg.pluralize}/new",   to: "#{seg.pluralize}#new",     as: "new_#{seg}"
  get     "#{base}/:#{seg}_id/edit",        to: "#{seg.pluralize}#edit",    as: "edit_#{seg}"
  get     "#{base}/:#{seg}_id",             to: "#{seg.pluralize}#show",    as: seg
  patch   "#{base}/:#{seg}_id",             to: "#{seg.pluralize}#update"
  put     "#{base}/:#{seg}_id",             to: "#{seg.pluralize}#update"
  delete  "#{base}/:#{seg}_id",             to: "#{seg.pluralize}#destroy"
  base << "/:#{seg}_id"
end
```

Which yields:

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                     Controller#Action
       locations GET    /locations(.:format)                                                            locations#index
                 POST   /locations(.:format)                                                            locations#create
    new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)                                                        locations#new
   edit_location GET    /locations/:location_id/edit(.:format)                                          locations#edit
        location GET    /locations/:location_id(.:format)                                               locations#show
                 PATCH  /locations/:location_id(.:format)                                               locations#update
                 PUT    /locations/:location_id(.:format)                                               locations#update
                 DELETE /locations/:location_id(.:format)                                               locations#destroy
      categories GET    /locations/:location_id/categories(.:format)                                    categories#index
                 POST   /locations/:location_id/categories(.:format)                                    categories#create
    new_category GET    /locations/:location_id/categories/new(.:format)                                categories#new
   edit_category GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/edit(.:format)                             categories#edit
        category GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id(.:format)                                  categories#show
                 PATCH  /locations/:location_id/:category_id(.:format)                                  categories#update
                 PUT    /locations/:location_id/:category_id(.:format)                                  categories#update
                 DELETE /locations/:location_id/:category_id(.:format)                                  categories#destroy
   subcategories GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/subcategories(.:format)                    subcategories#index
                 POST   /locations/:location_id/:category_id/subcategories(.:format)                    subcategories#create
 new_subcategory GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/subcategories/new(.:format)                subcategories#new
edit_subcategory GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/edit(.:format)             subcategories#edit
     subcategory GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id(.:format)                  subcategories#show
                 PATCH  /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id(.:format)                  subcategories#update
                 PUT    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id(.:format)                  subcategories#update
                 DELETE /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id(.:format)                  subcategories#destroy
        products GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/products(.:format)         products#index
                 POST   /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/products(.:format)         products#create
     new_product GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/products/new(.:format)     products#new
    edit_product GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id/edit(.:format) products#edit
         product GET    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id(.:format)      products#show
                 PATCH  /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id(.:format)      products#update
                 PUT    /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id(.:format)      products#update
                 DELETE /locations/:location_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id(.:format)      products#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it makes me feel dirty to do this, but this works by adding another set of routes for the edit and new methods.

```
resources :locations, only: [:edit, :new] do
  resources :categories, only: [:edit, :new] do
    resources :subcategories, only: [:edit, :new] do
      resources :products, only: [:edit, :new]
    end
  end
end

resources :locations do
  resources :categories, path: '' do
    resources :subcategories, path: '' do
      resources :products, path: ''
    end
  end
end
```